# How to run more than one Pomodoro timer in one page built in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, dom

I am new to web development. What I am trying to do is run more than one Pomodoro timer built with JavaScript in parallel. The problem is when I click on the second start button the first timer stops working.
The goal is each timer should work separately and should show different times when I press the start button.
Sorry for bad css style it is not responsive!
Can anyone help me to find the solution?

```js
const p_Tag = document.querySelectorAll('.text');

  p_Tag.forEach(a => {
    if (a.textContent === "Next Correction") {
      a.parentNode.classList.add("isTimer")
    }
  })
  const getTimerContainer = document.querySelectorAll(".item");

  let hasclass = false;
  getTimerContainer.forEach(check => {
    if (check.classList.contains('isTimer')) {
      hasclass = true;
      const timerContainer = document.createElement("div");
      timerContainer.classList.add("timer");
      
      check.append(timerContainer)
    }
  });
  if (hasclass === true) {
    let id = 0;
    const timer = document.querySelectorAll(".timer");
    let settedTime = '02:⏰';
      const place = "beforeend";
      

    timer.forEach(t => {
      const timerElm = `
     <figure class="clock">
      <div class="numberContainer">
      <p class="mins" id="hr${id}">00</p>
      <p>:</p>
      <p class="secs" id="min${id}">00</p>
      <br>
      <p class="settedTime">${settedTime}</p>
      </div>
      <audio
        src="bell.mp3"
      ></audio>
      <svg class="progress-ring" height="200" width="200">
       
        <circle
          class="progress-ring__circle2"
          stroke-width="10"
          fill="transparent"
          r="80"
          cx="100"
          cy="100"
        />
      <circle
          class="progress-ring__circle"
          stroke-width="15"
          fill="transparent"
          r="80"
          cx="100"
          cy="100"
          id="${id}"
        />
      </svg>
     </figure>

      <div class="btn-group">
        <button class="start" id="s${id}">Start</button>
        <button class="reset" id="r${id}">Reset</button>
        <button class="halt" id="h${id}">Pause</button>
      </div>     
    </div>
     `;
      t.insertAdjacentHTML(place, timerElm);
      id++
      
    })
   
 
 
};

const bell = document.querySelectorAll("audio");
const minutes = document.querySelectorAll(".mins");
const secondes = document.querySelectorAll(".secs");
const startBtn = document.querySelectorAll(".start");
const pauseBtn = document.querySelectorAll(".halt");
const clockframe = document.querySelectorAll(".progress-ring__circle2");
let initial, totalsecs, perc, paused, mins, seconds;

const circleUp = document.querySelectorAll(".progress-ring__circle")
const circle = document.querySelector(".progress-ring__circle");
const radius = circle.r.baseVal.value;

const circumference = radius * 2 * Math.PI;
let idOfSec = null;
let idOfStartBtn=0;

function setId(t){
    t.forEach(tId=>{tId.addEventListener("click",(e)=>{
        const item= e.target;
        const isId = parseInt(item.id.split("").pop())
        
        idOfStartBtn = isId
       })
    })
}


const dasharray = circle.style.strokeDasharray = circumference;
const dashoffset= circle.style.strokeDashoffset = circumference;
//console.log("this is the dasharray: ", dasharray);
//console.log("this is the dashoffset: ", dashoffset);


function setProgress(percent) {
  const offset = circumference - (percent / 100) * circumference;
  //console.log("this is the offset ", offset)
  //circleUp.forEach(offset1 => offset1.style.strokeDashoffset= offset)
  circle.style.strokeDashoffset = offset ;
}


document.getElementById("s" + idOfStartBtn).addEventListener("click", () => {
  setId(startBtn)
  mins = 1;
  seconds = mins * 60;
  totalsecs = mins * 60;
  setTimeout(decremenT(idOfStartBtn), 60);
  //startBtn.style.transform = "scale(1)";
  paused = false;

})

document.getElementById("r" + idOfStartBtn).addEventListener("click", () => {
  //startBtn.style.transform = "scale(1)";
  clearTimeout(initial);
  setProgress(0);
  document.getElementById("hr"+idOfStartBtn).textContent = '00';
  document.getElementById("min"+idOfStartBtn).textContent = '00';
});
 
document.getElementById("h" + idOfStartBtn).addEventListener("click", () => {
  if (paused === undefined) {
    return;
  }
  if (paused) {
    paused = false;
    initial = setTimeout(`decremenT(${idOfStartBtn})`, 60);
    pause.textContent = "Pause";
    pause.classList.remove("Resume");
  } else {
    clearTimeout(initial);
    pause.textContent = "Resume";
    pause.classList.add("resume");
    paused = true;
  }
})

function decremenT(takeId) {
  //console.log("this is variable from decremenT:",takeId)
 
  let sec = document.getElementById(`hr${takeId}`).textContent = Math.floor(seconds / 60).toString().padStart(2, "0");
  document.getElementById(`min${takeId}`).textContent = seconds % 60 > 9 ? seconds % 60 : `0${seconds % 60}`;
 
  if (circle.classList.contains("danger")) {
    circle.classList.remove("danger");
    //minutes.classList.remove("beep");
    //secondes.classList.remove("beep");
  }

  if (seconds > 0) {
    perc = Math.ceil(((totalsecs - seconds) / totalsecs) * 100);
    setProgress(perc);
    seconds--;
    initial = window.setTimeout(`decremenT(${idOfStartBtn})`, 1000);
    if (seconds < 45) {
      circle.classList.add("danger");
      //minutes.classList.add("beep");
      //secondes.classList.add("beep");
    }
  } else {
    mins = 0;
    seconds = 0;
    bell.play();

   
  }
}
```

```css
*{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
body {
    
    background-color: #D9AFD9;
    background-image: linear-gradient(0deg, #D9AFD9 0%, #97D9E1 100%);
    font-family: 'Microsoft PhagsPa';
  
    height: 100vh;
    color: hsl(210, 10%, 10%);
    text-shadow: 0 1px 1px hsl(0deg 0% 100% / 50%);
  }
.item {
    border-radius: 15px;
   
    filter: brightness(95%);
    background-size: 450px;
    margin: 40px;
    box-shadow: 4px 4px 13px rgba(0,0,0,0.3), inset 10px 9px 18px rgba(0,0,0,0.55);
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .15);
    backdrop-filter: blur(5px);
  }
  
  .item:hover {
    color: rgb(77, 74, 137);
    opacity: 1;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 2rem;
    box-shadow: 6px 6px 15px rgba(0,0,0,0.3), inset 12px 11px 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.55);
  }
  #sortable li {
    position:relative;
    margin: 30px 30px 30px 0px;
    padding: 1px;
    width: 450px;
    height: 458px;
    font-size: 2em;
    text-align: center;
  }
  #sortable {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    list-style: none;
    justify-content: center;
    
    min-height: 200px;
    padding-bottom:100px;

  }
  

.clock {
    padding: 3px;
    display: flex;
   
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    height: 18vh;
    width:18vh;
    font-size: 24px;
  }
  
  .progress-ring {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10vh;
    left: 5vw;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  }
  
  .progress-ring__circle {
    transition: 0.5s;
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
    transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    stroke: rgba(142, 68, 173,1);
  }
  .progress-ring__circle2 {
    transition: 0.5s;
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
    transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    stroke: rgb(189, 195, 199);
  }
  .btn-group {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: start;
    align-items: start;
    height: 10%;
    position: relative;
    top: 10vh;
    right: 50px;
    z-index:1;
  }
  .timer {
    height: 212px;
    width: 212PX;
    position: relative;
    top: 200px;
    left:200px;
  }
  .start {
    background: rgb(48, 33, 253);
    color: white;
    margin-right: 5px;
    padding: 2px;
    width: 60px;
  }
  
  .break {
    background: rgb(0, 199, 116);
    color: #000000;
    margin-right:5px;
    padding:2px;
  }
  
  .reset {
    background: rgb(250, 69, 109);
    color: #000000;
    margin-right: 5px;
    padding: 2px;
    width: 60px;
  }
  
  .halt {
    background: rgb(253, 143, 17);
    padding: 2px;
    width: 60px
  }
  
  .resume {
    background: rgb(131, 10, 252);
    color: white;
    width: 60px;
  }
  
  .danger {
    stroke: rgba(243, 17, 28, 1);
    animation: pulse 0.9s ease-in-out infinite;
  }
  .beep {
    color: rgba(192, 57, 43,1.0);
    animation: beep 0.9s infinite;
    border-radius:50%;
  }
  
  .settedTime {
    position: absolute;
    top: 70px;
    font-size: 14px;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 0px;
    opacity:.5;
  }
  .numberContainer {
    display: inline-flex;
    justify-content: center;
  }
  
  @keyframes pulse {
    0%,100% {
      transform: rotate(-90deg) scale(1);
      
    }
  
    50% {
      transform: rotate(-90deg) scale(1.04);
      box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px rgba(243, 17, 28, 0.8);
    }
  
    75% {
      transform: rotate(-90deg) scale(1.01);
    }
  }
  @keyframes beep {
    0% {
      transform: scale(0.9);
      box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(192, 57, 43,0.2);
    }
  
    70% {
      transform: scale(1);
      box-shadow: 0 0 0 20px rgba(192, 57, 43,0);
    }
  
    100% {
      transform: scale(0.9);
    }
  }
  
  
  
  .text {
    position: absolute;
    top: 412px;
    text-align: center;
    /*border-top: solid;*/
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    
    <title>Timer</title>
</head>
<body>
    <ul id="sortable" class="row itemContainer">
        <li class="item col-xs-4 col-sm-2 col-md-1">
            
           <p class="text">Next Correction</p>
           <div class="inner"><div class="resize"></div></div>
           
 </li>
<li class="item col-xs-4 col-sm-2 col-md-1 ">
    
   <p class="text">Next Correction</p>
   <div class="inner"><div class="resize"></div></div>
   
</li>
<li class="item col-xs-4 col-sm-2 col-md-1 " >
  
   <p class="text">Next Correction</p>
   <div class="inner"><div class="resize"></div></div>
   
</li>
    </ul>
 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: first issue is that `idOfStartBtn` is a global ... so when you use it in the rest of the code, it is meaningless